# Problem Unit Testing ActiveResource Model with HttpMock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activeresource

I'm working on unit testing an `ActiveResource` model in my Rails application. I have my `ActiveResource::HttpMock` code in my test file as follows:

```
ActiveResource::HttpMock.respond_to do |mock|
  mock.get "/audience/42/people/1.xml", {"Authorization" => "Basic VTExbTJCTzhkZzNMOmFpdU1nbHZJT2taakdPV3A=", "Accept" => "application/xml"}, @some_ivar
end
```

When I run my test, I get this message:

```
ActiveResource::InvalidRequestError: No response recorded for <GET: /audiences/42/people.xml?email_address=user%40domain.tld [AuthorizationBasic VTExbTJCTzhkZzNMOmFpdU1nbHZJT2taakdPV3A=Acceptapplication/xml] ()>
```

I'm sure this is a simple matter of not having my `HttpMock` configured properly, but at this point I'm unsure how to adjust to make the HttpMock object actually respond to the method call.

(If it's any help, this is related to the [StreamSend API](http://app.streamsend.com/docs/api/index.html)'s PeopleController. Since this is a third party API endpoint and there isn't a developer sandbox, mocking is really the only way to go on this one I think.)

Answer (score 0):

Restraining the scope of `require 'active_resource/http_mock'` fixed this error for me. See 
[this link](http://www.johnnypez.com/design-development/problem-testing-activeresource-with-mocks-in-rails/comment-page-1/).